# Two finite or infinite disjoint subseries in $\ell_1$ with the same value

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)$ be a real sequence in $\ell_1$ with strictly positive values such that:
$$
(\star)\quad \quad 
x_k\le \sum_{n>k}x_n \text{ for all }k \in \mathbf{N}.
$$

> **Question.** Is it true that for every partition $\{A,B\}$ of $\mathbf{N}$ into infinite sets there exist nonempty sets $A_0\subseteq A$ and $B_0\subseteq B$ such that
> $$
> \sum_{n \in A_0} x_n = \sum_{n \in B_0} x_n \text{ }?
> $$

The answer is surely negative without condition $(\star)$. Indeed, it is enough to let $(x_n)$ be a sequence which is rapidly convergent to $0$ (e.g., the sequence of reciprocals of factorials), and then consider an arbitrary partition of $\mathbf{N}$ into two infinite sets. The reason is that every representation of the type $\sum_{n \in A}x_n$ is at most unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence $x_n=1/2^n$ satisfies $(\star)$ with equality, yet the sums of infinite subsequences of $\{x_n\}$ are all distinct. Moreover, if $A$ consists of all even integers in $\mathbb N$ and $B=\mathbb N \setminus A$, then all sums of subsets of $A$ differ from sums of subsets of $B$.

Comment: OK,  see the additional details.